# missed out cream of tartar in chiffon recipe

Tags: sponge-cake

I forgot to add cream of tartar to my egg whites as inwas making a chiffon cake. what happens if you missed out adding cream of tartar to the egg whites for your chiffon cake recipe. will it alter the taste, texturre or fluffiness ofvthe cake?

Comment: Did you *not* bake the cake? Otherwise you would know by now.

Answer (score 6):

It will most likely turn out fine.  Cream of tarter is sometimes added when beating egg whites to enhance the stability of the foam that you form.  The egg whites beat into peaks on their own, but the cream of tarter is an accelerator of this process and also a bit of a preservative of the structure when you're folding in the rest of the batter. A bit of an "insurance policy" if you will.

And no, it won't affect the taste either.

Comment: A meringue made with cream of tartar (in the quantities suggested by recipes) is noticably more sour than one made with just egg.